# $\|Tx\|\ge c\|x\|\iff\ker T=\{0\}\,\,\text{and}\,\,\text{ran}\,T$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $B,C$ be Banach spaces and $T:$ $B\to C$ be bounded and linear. Show that there is a $c>0$ such that $\|Tx\|_C\ge c\|x\|_B$ for all $x\in B$, if and only if $\ker T=\{0\}$ and $\text{ran}\, T$ is closed.

$\implies$ In this direction, showing that $\ker T=\{0\}$ is easy enough. Let $x\in\ker T$, then
\begin{align*}
&0=\|0\|_C=\|Tx\|_C\ge c\|x\|_B\\
\implies &0\ge\|x\|_B\\
\implies&0=\|x\|_B\\
\implies&0=x\\
\implies&\ker T=\{0\}.
\end{align*}
But I am having more difficulty in showing that the range is closed.

$\Longleftarrow$ In this direction I am trying to go by way of contradiction and assuming that for any $c>0$ there exists an $x\in B$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|Tx\|_C<c\|x\|_B,
\end{align*}
then contradict the fact that $\ker T=\{0\}$ or that $\text{ran}\,T$ is closed but I am having some trouble there as well.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence, $\|T(x_n)-T(x_m)\|=\|T(x_n-x_m)\|\geq c\|x_n-x_m\|$ implies that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges towards $x$ since the space is Banach. $T(x)=lim_nT(x_n)$.

For the other side, $T(B)$ is Banach. This implies that $T':B\rightarrow T(B)$ defined by $T'(x)=T(x)$ is bijective. The open mapping theorem implies that it is invertible. ${T'}^{-1}$ is continuous. This implies that there exists $c$ such that $\|{T'}^{-1}(y)\|\leq {1\over c}\|y\|$. Write $y=T(x)$, we deduce that $\|T(x)\|\geq c\|x\|$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!